# Setting Individual SO_TIMEOUT

Tags: java, sockets, io

Suppose I have multiple socket connections, each of which may want to switch between an infinite timeout and a finite timeout, individually, for I/O operations. The documentation for `Socket.setSoTimeout()` implies that calling `setSoTimeout()` on any `Socket` will change the timeouts for all `Socket` objects, since the field `SocketOptions.SO_TIMEOUT` is static.

Is there any way to set the timeouts for individual `Socket` objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging around the source code for `java.net.Socket`, it seems that `SocketOptions.SO_TIMEOUT` is not a global timeout value. Rather, it's some sort of ID for an option, and the actual timeout value is retrieved through the `SocketImpl` instance using said ID.

```
public synchronized int getSoTimeout() throws SocketException {
    if (isClosed())
        throw new SocketException("Socket is closed");
    Object o = getImpl().getOption(SocketOptions.SO_TIMEOUT);
    /* extra type safety */
    if (o instanceof Integer) {
        return ((Integer) o).intValue();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not imply that it will change `timeout` for all the sockets. it will only change `timeout` for associated socket object. Excerpts from java docs of 
[Socket#setSoTimeout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout(int))

> Enable/disable SO_TIMEOUT with the specified timeout, in milliseconds.
>   With this option set to a non-zero timeout, a read() call on the
>   InputStream associated with **this Socket** will block for only this
>   amount of time. If the timeout expires, a
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised, though the Socket is still
>   valid. The option must be enabled prior to entering the blocking
>   operation to have effect. The timeout must be > 0. A timeout of zero
>   is interpreted as an infinite timeout.